# join to view table convert

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-5, mysqli

I wanna convert left join to `view table`.

`Following is my SQL`

```
 SELECT d.account_no, COALESCE(d.deposits, 0) - COALESCE(w.withdrawals, 0) 
   AS balance
  FROM (SELECT account_no, SUM(deposit_amount) AS deposits
   FROM deposits
  GROUP BY account_no) d
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT account_no, SUM(withdraw_amount) AS withdrawals
       FROM withdraws
       GROUP BY account_no) w ON w.account_no = d.account_no
```

i want to create `view` table.

How can i make this? Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you asking how to create a view? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html

Comment: This might be better written unioning the 2 tables and then conditionally aggregating deposits and withdrawals.

Comment: i want to covert `left join` to view table

Comment: The view syntax is straightforward what problem are you having? (you cannot create a view as part of a select statement)

Comment: how can create view table . i want same result

Comment: Go on, read the docs and have a go.

Comment: @HasanSheikh . . . What is a "view table"?  SQL has "views".  SQL has "tables".  But I don't know what "view table" is.

Answer (score 0):

Create the view  (once) and use in left join

```
CREATE  VIEW my_view AS 
SELECT account_no, SUM(withdraw_amount) AS withdrawals
       FROM withdraws
       GROUP BY account_no
;


SELECT d.account_no, COALESCE(d.deposits, 0) - COALESCE(w.withdrawals, 0) 
 AS balance
FROM (SELECT account_no, SUM(deposit_amount) AS deposits
 FROM deposits
GROUP BY account_no) d
LEFT JOIN my_view  w ON w.account_no = d.account_no
```

Comment: first error:  CREATE my_view VIEW AS 
SELECT account_no, SUM(withdraw_amount) AS withdrawals
       FROM withdraws
       GROUP BY account_no

Comment: Second Error : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'my_view VIEW AS 
SELECT account_no, SUM(withdraw_amount) AS withdrawals
      ' at line 1